# using the ssh keys on other machine for remote login

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-12.04, ssh-keys

I have started using ssh keys login for my new VPS. It works on the work machine as i have placed the public key on the server using this ssh-copy-id command.

Successfully, i was able to login without password from my work machine.

Now for checking the security, i tried logging in from some other machine that didn't had the private key installed. I wasn't able to login and that was perfect.

Now i do work from home as well. I want to know the method for taking the private key from my office pc and placing it in my home pc so that i am able to login from there as well without generating a second key.

I am on ubuntu 12.0 LTS on both home and work pcs.

**EDIT**

Further, is it the case that once i start using ssh keys for authentication on a specific computer, i can in no way access/login to server from any other other computer until and unless i have private key? Please cast some light over the subject as i am a bit confused now :(

Answer (score 1):

you can copy the `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` file. this contains your private key and is the only one you need to move your ssh-identity.

i really recommend to create another key, though.

Comment: so you say that i should create separate keys for each of the pcs that i use for accessing? Please explain the reason behind the same.

Comment: @beNerd I recommend to use two keys. One at work and one at home.

Comment: @jgb I have a few confusions regarding this. First is that what if my work pc gets crashed today. Provided i am not using any other key anywhere, will there be no way of accessing my server from then on? what are the other implications.

Comment: If you use public key authentication only, you will not be able to log in or restore your private key if you lose it @beNerd

Comment: Btw: this is not the reason why I recommend to use two keys. it is more a matter of separating private and business.

Comment: i guess i should stick to password authentication instead of keys one. If i loose hold of my systems due to any reason, my server will not be usable from SSH. i will have to reprovision it again. Correct me if i am wrong !!

Comment: keys are much better than passwords (reason: security). multiple keys are better than one (reason: little overhead and better separation of concerns). if you are concerned about losing access to a server where you have keys on two different machines, you are doing your backups wrong. on a site note, password login can be left enabled for local logins, but there really is no reason to enable it with ssh.

Comment: @beNerd If you're afraid to lose your key(s), you should think about backups first.